# Best way to reduce physical space of DB

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2003

i have a problem. My SQL Server is soon running out of space. 
I've already tried to delete some unused tables in different DBs but that doesnt change the free disk space somehow. I read about some commands to shrink the database, but found several articles why not to use them.
http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/

Now i wanted to ask what i should do. on the server itself i've seen that the tempdb.mdf file uses the most space. i'd like to get rid of the problem, but i dont know what to do without causing some trouble. is there a secure way to reduce the DB size of the tempdb? i'm sure that the tempdb has some old temporary data in it, because its more than 177GB big. and the other databases summed up are not more than 10GB.

Thanks in advance for your posts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link about [tempdb Database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx) from Microsoft Technet (first google result when searching for "tempdb" by the way). Indicates that the database is created each time the server is restarted, so I would probably give that a go...

Power Off Power On (POPO) is one of the best troubleshooting steps to try.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I am not allowed to power off the server. i'll have to wait until my supervisor shows up so I can ask him. if that will to the trick i'll mark your answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly! thanks alot. from now on i'll keep POPO in mind :-)

Comment: Heh, didn't know that. That's even better! :P
Glad it worked for you.